# Get AWS Access Key ID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

When IAM user is making an AWS API request using aws cli, is there a call to get aws access key id?

I know I can get the username with `aws sts get-caller-identity`, but not sure how to determine effective aws access key id? Searched aws iam docs, but haven't found a relevant call.

I already have the keys, but credentials might be coming from anywhere in the Credentials Provider (environment variables, config file, EC2 metadata) so I need to be able to determine active key identifier.

Comment: See [Managing access keys (console)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html#Using_CreateAccessKey). You need to create a set.

Comment: What do you mean by "how to determine effective aws access key id"? Are you saying that the credentials might be coming from anywhere in the Credentials Provider (environment variables, config file, EC2 metadata) so you're not sure which credentials it is using? More information, please.

Comment: @jarmod I already have keys.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, I need to determine which specific set of credentials I'm using. Amended the question.

Comment: See if `aws configure list` helps you.

Answer (score 1):

We can find access key IDs using the following command. This will give all the access key IDs associated with the specified IAM user

```
aws iam list-access-keys --user [Username]
```

We will get an output similar to this:

```
{
    "AccessKeyMetadata": [
        {
            "UserName": "...",
            "AccessKeyId": "...",
            "Status": "Active",
            "CreateDate": "2023-05-14T09:51:39+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if the are two active keys associated with user, how do I know which one I'm using?

Comment: Once we get a list of access keys, we can find when a particular access key was last used => `aws iam get-access-key-last-used --access-key-id ABCD3EXAMPLE`. Then it becomes easier to find the most recently used access key with this command.